# Hide and Seek Environment for MARL

Tags: windows, environment, wsl-2, mujoco, multi-agent-reinforcement-learning

I am trying/want to train a Hide and seek environment in MARL. But all the existing MARL-Model-Codes (for example MARLlib, VACL, mujoco-worlgen-environment,...) don't have the environment yet, don't really run yet (pretty new), don't really run for windows and those with mujoco-worldgen don't always run on my Laptop.

I tried (Hide and seek environment inculded) mujoco-worlgen-environment on Windows 1.5 wasn't great (mj_ray not in dict2) for it and 2.0 didn't build wheel on Windows. On WSL it lead to GLSW error which I couldn't fix without making everything worse.

I tried VACL (Variational-Automatic-Curriculum-Learning) (Hide and Seek environment inculded) which I found pretty cool, due to an online tool where the data should be uploaded but I didn't manage to train anything because it got stuck a lot and somehow was always different errors for everytime running/reopening WSL

I managed to train simple_Tag from MPE Pettingzoo on MARLlib but the Hide and seek doesnt exist yet. I am working on creating a new env there but according to the documentation I need ma-gym for that (which needs gym 0.20.0) but marllib needs 0.21.0 where I was already informed, during pre-installing ma-gym, that one of them will have a dependency conflict. Furthermore is there a problem with rendering due to no Display being found. All fixes over Jupyternotbook on a conda activate env and WSL nearly destroyed everything.
"Sadly" MARLlib was updated a week ago, which means it will be a while until HaS env will be available.

Has anyone already managed to train a Model of Hide And seek with MARL? Or better asked, managed to successfully create (any) env yourself to put into a MARL?

First time asking something on StackOverflow so sorry if I did something wrong. Please tell me

I have:
Windows 10
WSL2 with Ubuntu 20.04 (python3.8.13) or 18.04 (Python 3.6.2)

Hope somebody knows something

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.